# Game Center how to have two games use the same leaderboard

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have a full version and a lite version of a game and i want them both to use the same leaderboard, can some one tell me how to accomplish this in iTunes connect. I've made another game using just one leaderboard but don't know how to have two games use the same leaderboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, I have that with three pairs of games I have made. To this you need to go to iTunes Connect > go to your apps > go to the app > manage game center. There you will be able to add it to a group of apps. This will change the leaderboard identifier so that it has to start with "grp."

For developer information you can go to [iTunes Connect Game Center Guide Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Groups/Groups.html)